# Why is'nt my program finding the solution to Peg Solitaire and keeps running forever?

Tags: java

I wanted to write a program to solve Peg Solitaire and made an 
       almost 
       presentable program("almost" because I have stored the steps in a 3D 
       array to print but since my program never ends, I haven't written that part yet). I 
         *have made sure recursion ends after 32 times but still, it goes on. 
        I used the debugger but the working for the first few recursions seems fine(of 
        course 
         it's way too much to check everything). My program tries every combination 
         of 
         moving marbles to solve the game. Someone, please help to find the mistake!
          (Don't mind the codes used to debug)

```
 import java.util.*;

 class Brainvita2

{

 static char a[][][];

 final static int n=7;

 static int max=0;

 static boolean found;

 public static void Do(int c,char temp[][],char b[][][])

 {

if(found) 

 return;

 if(oneMarble(temp))

 {
    a=b;

    found=true;

    System.out.println("Found answer.");

    return;

  }

if(c==33)

return;

    int d[][]=coordinates_Of_Empty(temp);

    for(int i=0 ; i < d.length ; i++)

   {

     if(d[i][0]>1)

   {

   if((temp[(d[i][0])-1][(d[i][1])]=='O')&&(temp[(d[i][0])-2][(d[i][1])]=='O'))

        {

            char temp3[][]=new char[n][n];

            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
                {
                    temp3[j][k]=temp[j][k];
                }
            }
            temp3[(d[i][0])-2][(d[i][1])]=' ';
            temp3[(d[i][0])-1][(d[i][1])]=' ';
            temp3[(d[i][0])][(d[i][1])]='O';
            char temp2[][][]=new char[b.length+1][n][n];
            for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            {
                for(int l=0;l<n;l++)
                {
                    temp2[j][k][l]=b[j][k][l];
                }
            }
            }
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            {
                temp2[b.length][j][k]=temp3[j][k];
            }
            }
            Do(c+1,temp3,temp2);
        }
        }
        if(d[i][0]<n-2)
        {
        if((temp[(d[i][0])+1][(d[i][1])]=='O')&&(temp[(d[i][0])+2][(d[i][1])]=='O'))
        {
            char temp3[][]=new char[n][n];
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
                {
                    temp3[j][k]=temp[j][k];
                }
            }
            temp3[(d[i][0])+2][(d[i][1])]=' ';
            temp3[(d[i][0])+1][(d[i][1])]=' ';
            temp3[(d[i][0])][(d[i][1])]='O';
            char temp2[][][]=new char[b.length+1][n][n];
            for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            {
                for(int l=0;l<n;l++)
                {
                    temp2[j][k][l]=b[j][k][l];
                }
            }
            }
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            {
                temp2[b.length][j][k]=temp3[j][k];
            }
            }
            Do(c+1,temp3,temp2);
        }
        }
        if(d[i][1]>1)
        {
        if((temp[(d[i][0])][(d[i][1])-1]=='O')&&(temp[(d[i][0])][(d[i][1])-2]=='O'))
        {
            char temp3[][]=new char[n][n];
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
                {
                    temp3[j][k]=temp[j][k];
                }
            }
            temp3[(d[i][0])][(d[i][1])-2]=' ';
            temp3[(d[i][0])][(d[i][1])-1]=' ';
            temp3[(d[i][0])][(d[i][1])]='O';
            char temp2[][][]=new char[b.length+1][n][n];
            for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            {
                for(int l=0;l<n;l++)
                {
                    temp2[j][k][l]=b[j][k][l];
                }
            }
            }
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            {
                temp2[b.length][j][k]=temp3[j][k];
            }
            }
            Do(c+1,temp3,temp2);
        }
        }
        if(d[i][1]<n-2)
        {

        if((temp[(d[i][0])][(d[i][1])+2]=='O')&&(temp[(d[i][0])][(d[i][1])+1]=='O'))
        {
            char temp3[][]=new char[n][n];

            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)

            {

                for(int k=0;k<n;k++)

                {

                    temp3[j][k]=temp[j][k];

                }

            }

            temp3[(d[i][0])][(d[i][1])+2]=' ';

            temp3[(d[i][0])][(d[i][1])+1]=' ';

            temp3[(d[i][0])][(d[i][1])]='O';

            char temp2[][][]=new char[b.length+1][n][n];

            for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            {
                for(int l=0;l<n;l++)
                {
                    temp2[j][k][l]=b[j][k][l];
                }
            }
            }

            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)

            {

                for(int k=0;k<n;k++)

            {

                temp2[b.length][j][k]=temp3[j][k];

            }

            }

            Do(c+1,temp3,temp2);

        }


        }


   //The below few codes are just to find errors(to debug)


        if(max<c)

        {

            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)

            {

                for(int k=0;k<n;k++)

            {

                System.out.print(temp[j][k]+"|");

            }

              System.out.println();

              max=c;

          }

          System.out.println("Highest c value = "+c);

          System.out.println("-----------------------------------");

          System.out.println();

        }

   }

}
public static void main()
{
  char p[][]={{'*','*','O','O','O','*','*'},{'*','*','O','O','O','*','*'},{'O','O','O','O','O','O','O'},{'O','O','O',' ','O','O','O'},{'O','O','O','O','O','O','O'},{'*','*','O','O','O','*','*'},{'*','*','O','O','O','*','*'}};
  char q[][][]={{{'*','*','O','O','O','*','*'},{'*','*','O','O','O','*','*'},{'O','O','O','O','O','O','O'},{'O','O','O',' ','O','O','O'},{'O','O','O','O','O','O','O'},{'*','*','O','O','O','*','*'},{'*','*','O','O','O','*','*'}}};
  found=false;
  Do(1,p,q);
}
  public static int[][] coordinates_Of_Empty(char x[][])
{
    int c=0,c2=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(x[i][j]==' ')
            c++;
        }
    }
    int t[][]=new int[c][2];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(x[i][j]==' ')
            {
                t[c2][0]=i;
                t[c2][1]=j;
                c2++;
            }
        }
    }
    return t;
}
public static boolean oneMarble(char temp[][])
{
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(temp.length>n)
            c+=0;
            if(temp[i][j]=='O')
            c++;
        }
    }
    if(c==1)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}

}

     //Expected to print board with one marble(during debug).
     //Instead printed all boards till 3 marbles.
```

Comment: I think this is better situated herre: [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @AmirSchnell - No it isn't.  A question that asks for help with debugging will be rejected there.

Comment: Do you know you can add comments within your code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell your code works as it should. I would guess your biggest problem is time. Your program "never ends" because "33-Hole Peg Solitaire" has 187,636,299 different game patterns you can encounter ([link](http://www.durangobill.com/Peg33.html)) (many of them more than once) therefor it seems like it never finishes.

Your:

```
if(c==33)
    return;
```

which I guess you meant when you said: "I *have made sure recursion ends after 32 times but still it goes on." does nothing since "c" never gets that large. As far as I can tell "c" increments each time the recursion reaches a deeper level. It does so when a piece is removed since "c" starts at 1 and there are 32 pieces it would reach 33 when no pieces are left.

The maximum "max" reaches is 30 since it often stops with 3 pieces left due to the lack of possible moves. To find a solution it just needs a lot of time. If you start with an easier pattern that needs only a view moves to complete the program finishes in a rather short time.

To print only the solution try printing temp in:

```
if (oneMarble(temp))
{
    a = b;
    found = true;
    System.out.println("Found answer.");
    return;
}
```

which I guess you meant by "Expected to print a board with one marble(during debug).".